# how teamcity push jar to Artifactory automatically

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, artifactory

I am using teamcity to do java building. and I manually deployed the jar to http://artifactory.companyname.net/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/com/companyname/myproject/common/myproject-common (the tree is com.companyname.myproject.common).

How to configure the teamcity to push the jar automatically? SHould I configure `Artifact paths:` in the build page of teamcity project?

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure TeamCity Artifactory Plug-in

> Artifactory provides tight integration with TeamCity CI Server through the TeamCity Artifactory Plug-in. Beyond managing efficient deployment of your artifacts to Artifactory

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plug-in

[TeamCity Artifactory Plugin - Release Management](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management)